# How to CRUD child document by elasticsearch-php

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-php. I want to create new, update, delete child document.

With parent document I can use

```
    $Params = array();
    $Params ['index'] = 'vision';
    $Params ['type']  = 'type';
    $Params ['id']             = 1590353;
    $Params ['body']['doc']    = array('field' => 'value');

    $retUpdate = $client->update($Params );
```

But with child document, I always get error

```
{"error":"RoutingMissingException[routing is required for [vision]/[child_type]/[1590354]]","status":400}
```

How can I do it?

---

I think that is because of routing

with parent I can access URL: **localhost:9200/vision/mt_customer/1590354?pretty**

But I got error routing when access child document: **localhost:9200/vision/child_type/12314?pretty**

Comment: will $Params ['body']= array('field' => 'value');
 works??

Comment: That is not working. Same error "Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception [ 400 ]:
{"error":"RoutingMissingException[routing is required for [vision]/[wk_call_list]/[156728]]","status":400}". I think that is because child document

Comment: can you get json equavalent of request ??

Comment: I think that is because routing:
With parent document: curl -XPOST  "localhost:9200/vision/mt_customer/_update" -d "{\
"sales\": \"5\"}". I use the same with child document but I got error.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem. With child document we need add parent into index.

Example:

```
    $searchParams['index'] = 'vision';
    $searchParams['type']  = 'child_type';
    $searchParams['id']             = 156728;
    $searchParams['parent']             = 1791035;
```